# A question about continuous functions and completeness theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For reference
http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/IntValueTheorem13.htm
In the proof of the IVM the author  chooses epsilon=f(a)/2 in them? 
If there are 3 cases how about epsilon=f(a)/3?

In other theorems , usually to show f(c)=0 or something similar , it seems to be the case to choose f(c)/2 if c€(a,b)

Does this something to do with the Completeness Theorem.

Comment: The cases are separate; the reason you pick $f(a)/2$ is just to ensure that all values stay away from $0$. You could pick $f(a)/3$, or $f(a)/150$, of $2f(a)/3$. Anything, so long as $0$ is not in the interval $(f(a)-\epsilon),f(a)+\epsilon)$. Don't confuse "three cases" with "divide by $3$".

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying this issue. It drove me nuts